# How can we add two objects from a ArrayList <Object>?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I recently started studying Java's `ArrayList` class, and learned about how we can use an `ArrayList <Object>` to hold elements of different class types. This question, however, confused me.

[image]

My general thinking pattern in answering this question was that we can first eliminate answers A and B, because the compiler would complain about using the `+` operator on two Objects that have not been cast. When I looked at answers C and D, however, it seemed to me that both of them would work correctly, because they both cast the values returns from `list.get()` to a type where the operator `+` is defined. This led me to choose answer E, as I believed both C and D could work in this piece of code.

As you can see, however, E was the wrong answer. To compound my confusion, I tested this piece of code on repl.it, where it was confirmed that answer choices A and B result in compilation errors while answer choices C and D both store the correct value of `9` into `i`. So now, I'm really confused. Is there some rule with `Object`s that I am glossing over here? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I can confirm that both c and d should work. Looks like an error with the test.

Comment: Was this a multiple choice answer or were you supposed to select only one option? And what does "more than one of these" mean? Are you supposed to select `e` when you know other ways to sum both numbers that is not listed there? If yes, then `e` is correct as well, because there are several other ways to fill the "blank".

Comment: I would say that 'c' is the more correct answer as the cast to ```int``` takes place on the entire ```list.get()``` operation. The key phrase being ```more correct```

Comment: @BigGuy the two statements are perfectly equivalent, because the derefence (`.`) has higher precedence than the cast. That's the reason you need to do `((Whatever)x).y()` if you want to cast `x` to `Whatever` before invoking the `y` method

Comment: @BigGuy sorry, method call, not derefernce. Too late to edit my comment

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca Oh I agree. In the real world that is. In the world of multiple choice tests however there is the concept of "more correct". I also object to ```ArrayList<Object>``` as it breaks type safety. but again, a test.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Object` as type parameter can allow the collection to hold any type of java object
2. Though this simplifies the writers, it places a huge burden on the readers to validate the types to avoid run time `ClassCastException`s. It behaves like pre-generic world

Regarding why `list.get()` is allowed in `c` and `d`:

1. `list.get(0)` will be first invoked and the result is casted to `int`. (since the type of values stored at `0` is `Integer`, it is perfectly valid to cast as `int` - actually cast to `Integer` and then unbox to `int`)
2. same applies for `list.get(2)`
3. if you meant about casting the reference before making a method call, then it will look like `((int)list).get(0))`. Unfortunately this is invalid due to the types used.

### More

1. Actually it will be interesting to add a long to the list `list.add(1L)`

```java
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1L);
(int) list.get(0) + (int) list.get(0);
```

2. Casting this to `int` will result in run time `ClassCastException`
   (something like `Long cannot be cast to Integer`)
3. This is because, even though, we apply the cast as primitive `int`, it actually does an evaluation of object hierarchy based on the reference(object type) and finds that `Integer` and `Long` are siblings and does not have a direct hierarchy and hence throw an `ClassCastException`